# JavaScript date conversion resulting in different values for Browser and Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a function to convert date time into  'en-NL' format.But it gives me different result in browser and nodejs

```
function convertDateTime(value){
    const timestamp = new Date(value);
    let date = timestamp.toLocaleDateString('en-NL');
    let time = timestamp.toLocaleTimeString('en-NL');
    return date + ' ' + time;
}
console.log(convertDateTime(1559742499937));
```

when i use this function in browser  it gives me following results:
05/06/2019 19:48:19
when i use this function in nodejs  it gives me following result :
6/5/2019 7:48:19 PM.
But  my result should be same in browser and nodejs.

Comment: which one is correct?

Comment: In this cases I would adopt a library like moment.js in both node and browser.

Comment: I would guess that the first one is correct. The "en-NL" locale is a little unusual; Node can be [augmented with ICU data at runtime.](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out -> `the locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely implementation dependent.`

Comment: But i need exactly same output in node js like browser

Comment: Then follow the advice given by Pointy - or there's a simpler way if you always want the same format

Comment: In browser date format is in DD/MM/YYYY but in node.js its format is in MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @MukeshBurnwalMike - yes, that's part of the problem Aunog is talking about - did you think he missed that?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of Date between browsers and node can differ a bit.

To avoid that issue, I suggest you to use a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) on both frontend and backend, afterward, you will be able to manage the format of the date and you should have the same value on both.

You can also force the format of the datetime with the following

```
moment().format('DD/MM/YY h:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to include momentjs just for this simple function, you can always write your code to return the exact format you need

```js
function convertDateTime(value){
    const t = new Date(value);
    const pad2 = n => ('0' + n).substr(-2);
    let date = `${pad2(t.getDate())}/${pad2(t.getMonth()+1)}/${t.getFullYear()}`
    let time = `${pad2(t.getHours())}:${pad2(t.getMinutes())}:${pad2(t.getSeconds())}`
    return date + ' ' + time;
}
console.log(convertDateTime(1559742499937));
```